# Regex to find <a> tags containing links to specific file types

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to write a small jQuery / javascript function that searches through all the links on a page, identifies the type of file to which the  tag links, and then adds an appropriate class. The purpose of this task is to style the links depending on the type of file at the other end of the link.

So far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rt-mainbody a').each(function(){
        linkURL = $(this).attr('href');
        var match = linkURL.match("^.*\.(pdf|PDF)$");
        if(match != null){$(this).addClass('pdf');}
    });
});
```

[Fiddle me this.](http://jsfiddle.net/jLXrf/)

And then I would continue the concept to identify, for example, spreadsheet files, Word documents, text files, jpgs, etc.

it works... but the thing is, to me this is super clunky because I have completely botched it together from odds and sods I've found around SO and the internet - I'm sure there must be a neater, more efficient, more readable way of doing this but I have no idea what it might be. Can someone give it a spit and polish for me, please?

Ideally the function should detect (a) that the extension is at the end of the href string, and (b) that the extension is preceded by a dot.

Thanks! :)

**EDIT**

Wow! Such a response! :) Thanks guys!

When I saw the method using simply the selector it was a bit of a facepalm moment - however the end user I am building this app for is linking to PDFs (and potentially other MIMEs) on a multitude of resource websites and has no control over the case usage of the filenames to which they'll be linking... using the selector is clearly not the way to go because the result would be so inconsistent.

**EDIT**

And the grand prize goes to @Dave Stein!! :D

The solution I will adopt is a "set it and leave it" script ([fiddle me that](http://jsfiddle.net/dDMKK/1/)) which will accommodate any extension, regardless of case, and all I need to do is tweak the CSS for each reasonable eventuality.

It's actually nice to learn that I was already fairly close to the best solution already... more through good luck than good judgement though XD

Comment: So does that edit mean I win the grand prize? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you don't want to use `regex` to search strings so I like that you narrowed it to just links. I saved off `$(this)` so you don't have to double call it. I also changed the `regex` so it's case insensitive. And lastly I made sure that the class is adding what the match was. This accomplish what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rt-mainbody a').each(function(){
        var $link = $(this),
            linkURL = $link.attr('href'),
            // I can't remember offhand but I think some extensions have numbers too
            match = linkURL.match( /^.*\.([a-z0-9]+)$/i );

        if( match != null ){
          $link.addClass( match[1].toLowerCase() );
        }
    });
});
```

Oh and I almost forgot, I made sure `linkURL` was no longer global. :)

Comment: I like this solution, Dave - this is tidy and it doesn't involve having to repeat the same line over and over... this makes me think, though - perhaps I could dispense with the regex entirely and simply add a class onto each <a> based on the extension to which the href links - e.g. we might end up with classes such as zip, html, exe, php, doc etc.

Comment: Yeah I can tweak that now actually

Comment: Actually... one small issue with this solution is that some <a>, for example, may be given the class "jpg" and others "jpeg"... not likely, I know, and it would only involve a tiny extra bit of CSS to accommodate this eventuality... but is there a quick way of amending the javascript to deal with this?

Comment: You can do an `if` for `jpeg` to switch it to `jpg` in the case that `if ( match[1].toLowerCase() === 'jpeg' )` but I think the extra rules for CSS would be nicer. That's just preference at that point.

Comment: Interesting - I spotted your edit and I was initially surprised to see the regex match still in there... however that is clearly the best (only?) way to extract the extension from the href, isn't it?

...and I agree with you on the CSS too - that would be the swiftest way to sort it.

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to do an `indexOf` to find where the period is and then perform a `substr` from that point. It's less elegant but probably a bit more performant - however unless you are doing some crazy things it shouldn't be noticable.

Answer (score 2):

["Attribute ends with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('#rt-mainbody a[href$=".pdf"], #rt-mainbody a[href$=".PDF"]').addClass('pdf')
```

**EDIT:** Or more generally and flexibly:

```
var types = {
  doc: ['doc', 'docx'],
  pdf: ['pdf'],
  // ...
};

function addLinkClasses(ancestor, types) {
  var $ancestor = $(ancestor);
  $.each(types, function(type, extensions) {
    selector = $.map(extensions, function(extension) {
        return 'a[href$=".' + extension + '"]';
      }).join(', ');
    $ancestor.find(selector).addClass(type);
  });
}

addLinkClasses('#rt-mainbody', types);
```

This is case sensitive, so I suggest you canonicalise all extensions to lowercase on your server.

Comment: This would make jQuery do all the work, to parse those strings, and run the regex itself. And it doesn't scale as well for multiple extensions. If he was only matching on PDFs I'd agree with you though.

Comment: @DaveStein: I don't know the internal workings of jQuery, but try this on this very page: `document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="selector/"]')`. Modern browsers can do it by themselves, if you let them (and while I'm not sure, I *think* jQuery delegates to `querySelectorAll` if it can). But even if it *was* slower, what this solution isn't, is "clunky".

Comment: Fair point, but then doesn't he have to build up for multiple extensions? His question has him wanting to do this for other things rather than PDFs. If the selector isn't case-insensitive isn't it a pain?

Comment: I added another answer below that combines what you wrote, plus making it easier to add multiple extensions

Comment: @DaveStein: As far as I understand, only PDFs should be classed as `.pdf`. Other extensions would presumably have another class. Besides, it's trivial to cobble together a selector for multiple extensions: `$.map(['doc', 'docx'], function(v) { return '[href$=".' + v + '"]'; }).join(', ')`... Now case sensitivity is a problem, but I am a firm believer extensions should be canonicalised to lowercase, and especially that anyone who names their file `fIlE.pDf` deserves everything they get.

Comment: You should update your answer to that and I agree if they do `.pDf` they deserve to be ignored :) Well if Doug wants to make sure that works too we'd need to use the `regex` option. It's funny we've had this debate and he hasn't commented back yet. It would be more ironic if he didn't pick an answer at all ha

Comment: Sorry guys - half a dozen responses in 30 minutes... I had some reading and head scratching to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex should be `/^.*\.(pdf)$/i` .

Answer (score 0):

use this regex (without quotes):

```
/\.(pdf|doc)$/i
```

this regex matches (case insensitive) anything that ends with .pdf, .doc etc.

for dynamic class:

```
    var match = linkURL.match(/\.(pdf|doc)$/i);
    match = match ? match[1].toLowerCase() : null;
    if (match != null) {
        $(this).addClass(match);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your selector (to find all links to pdf files)

```
a[href$=".pdf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, building off of @Amadan is:

```
var extensions = [
  'pdf',
  'jpg',
  'doc'
];

$.each( extensions, function( i, v) {
  $('#rt-mainbody').find( 'a[href$=".' + v + '"], a[href$=".' + v.toUpperCase() + '"]')
  .addClass( extension );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The onyl suggestion I would make is that you can change your match to inspect what is the file extension instead of having to do a different regex search for each possible file extension:

```
var linkURL = $(this).attr('href');  //<--you were accidentally declared linkURL as a global BTW.
var match = linkURL.match(/\.(.*)$/);
if(match != null){
   //we can extract the part between the parens in our regex
   var ext = match[1].toLowerCase() 
   switch(ext){
      case 'pdf': $(this).addClass('pdf'); break;
      case 'jpg': $(this).addClass('jpg'); break;
      //...
   }
}
```

This switch statement mostly useful if you want the option of using class names that are different from your file extensions. If the file extension is always the same you can consider changing the regex to something that fits the file extensions you want

```
/\.(pdf|jpg|txt)$/i  //i for "case insensitive"
```

and then just do

```
var ext = match[1].toLowerCase() 
$(this).addClass(ext);
```